# How to add item to an Array Type property in React Hook State Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Check my code below. I want to push an image file to product_images array. I tried using `concat()` also. But doesn't work.

```
const INITIAL_VENDOR_DATA = {
    store_name: "",
    store_contact_number: "",
    website_url:"",
    email:"",
    city:"",
    country:"",
    fb_url: "",
    categories:[],
    product_images:[],       <--------------- Array
    store_type:"",
    cp_name: "",
    cp_contact_number: ""
}

const[vendorData,setVendorData] = useState({data: INITIAL_VENDOR_DATA})    //initializing

//Doesn't add the image to product_images array . here image is just a Image File
setVendorData({
    data:{
        ...vendorData.data, 
        product_images:[...vendorData.data.product_images,image]        <----- ??
    }
})
```

Comment: That should work fine unless `vendorData` is a stale reference. If you plan on calling `setVendorData()` multiple times between renders, you should use the callback signature instead.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts , However it worked with a Functional update to the state.        `setVendorData(vendorData => { return { data: {...vendorData.data, product_images: vendorData.data.product_images.concat(image) }}} ) `

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 0):

What is contact() ? 
If you use the above in the proper context of a reactjs app it will work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const INITIAL_VENDOR_DATA = {
    store_name: "",
    store_contact_number: "",
    website_url:"",
    email:"",
    city:"",
    country:"",
    fb_url: "",
    categories:[],
    product_images:[],
    store_type:"",
    cp_name: "",
    cp_contact_number: ""
}


function App() {
  const[vendorData,setVendorData] = useState({data: INITIAL_VENDOR_DATA})    //initializing
  const image = "mypic.jpg";

  //Put the setVendorData in a click handler or on mount useEffect
  const handleClick = () =>{
    console.log('Inspect this and see it works', vendorData);
    setVendorData({
      data:{
        ...vendorData.data, 
        product_images:[...vendorData.data.product_images,image]  
      }
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Image</button>
        </p>
        <p style={{color: '#fff'}}>
        {vendorData.data.product_images && vendorData.data.product_images.map( (image) => image + '\n')}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can also do vendorData.data.product_images.push(image)

Comment: Thanks. It's actually `concat()`. However I fixed the problem using a functional update . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723314/how-to-add-item-to-an-array-type-property-in-react-hook-state-object/62723578#comment-110998355

Comment: push add element to end of array , concat merges arrays